# tracer and others damage output headshot vs torso

Tags: overwatch

Anybody know how to find (or already know) the damage output amount when landing headshots vs. torso hits? Specifically wondering with regards to Tracer, but would appreciate a complete low-down of all characters.

Answer (score 3):

Headshots deal double damage (2.0x). This is a global number that applies to all weapons that can headshot. The single exception is a scoped shot from Widowmaker, which has a multiplier of 2.5x.

This means landing 100% bodyshots has the same total damage output as getting 50% headshots and 50% misses.